# How to use infura API with web3 js?

Tags: web3js, javascript, infura, external-api

How to use infura API with web3 js?
Where should I put secret key?

Comment: See https://medium.com/coinmonks/deploy-your-smart-contract-directly-from-truffle-with-infura-ba1e1f1d40c2

Answer (score 8):

First, import web3 as such:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
```

Then instantiate a variable (in my case web3) and set a provider:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/INFURA_ACCESS_TOKEN:8545'))
```

Then you can use all the available web3 methods.

Hope it helped you!

Comment: This metod stopped working in browser right?
It is telling about CORS headers

Comment: @gkucmierz I think you have to use NodeJS. Browsers won't allow CORS unless it's HTTP(S) apparently.