# Can you query an account balance without needing metamask in browser?

Tags: web3js, react

I would like to use this code in order to get the account balance and display it on my react app.

```
  state = {
    croBalance: "",
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(
      "0xu28yjy9chxmhiruhgiwgm93h984hmxhumzmr"
    );
    const etherBalance = await web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether");
    const finalBalance = etherBalance.substring(0, 6);
    // console.log(balance);

    this.setState({ croBalance: finalBalance });
  }
```

here is my webb3.js file:

```
import Web3 from "web3";

window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

export default web3;
```

this code hangs when metamask is not on browser like mobile.  I would love to be able to query this address without users needing to confirm metamask account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi bro you just need to set the web3 from your react app and dont use metamask web3 .
You just need to do this way :
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/INFURA_ACCESS_TOKEN:8545'))
*You need to create an infuria account and add your infuria sting here , after that you will have web3 that work so you could use your function
const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(
"0xu28yjy9chxmhiruhgiwgm93h984hmxhumzmr"
);

Take a look here :)
[How to use infura API with web3 js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/how-to-use-infura-api-with-web3-js)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just use [Web3](https://github.com/web3/web3.js):

```
let web3 = new Web3('https://babel-api.testnet.iotex.io');
const result = await web3.eth.getBalance('0x6995......');
console.log(result);
const resultFormated = web3.utils.fromWei(result);
console.log(resultFormated);
```